# Falling "$" in console game

Tags: c#

another silly question from me :D
I want to make a console game where dollars are falling from above and we as the player have to catch them. I wrote a program that reads the buttons from the keyboard and allows us to move our I don't know, say character? To the right or to the left. Well, and all in all, I don't know how to create a method that will make the "$" fall from the top, meanwhile not interfering with the system of moving the "character" (I tried using SetCursorPosition but it didn't work well). I also thought whether to make the playing field as an array (I saw it somewhere on youtube, where a guy wrote Snake) but I don't know how to do it for the hell of it. This is how it looks now:

```
    class Program
{
    public static int x = 0, y = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string user = "@@@";

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start.");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();

        while (true)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                var command = Console.ReadKey().Key;

                switch (command)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                        if (x > 0)
                        {
                            x--;
                        }
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                        x++;
                        break;
                }
                Write(user, x, y);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Write(string user, int x = 0, int y = 0)
    {
        if (x >= 0)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, 20);
            Console.Write(user);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need a game for this. The $ is falling anyway :-). You can set `Console.CursorTop` and `Console.CursorLeft` before writing.

Comment: Of course calling _Console.Clear_ when you move the _user_ position will not help in keeping the $ in their position

Answer (score 0):

Just for illustration, I made a little application which shows random falling dollars

```cs
const int Rows = 20;
const int Columns = 60;
var buffer = new char[Rows][];

// Initialize jagged array
for (int r = 0; r < Rows; r++) {
    buffer[r] = new char[Columns];
}


var random = new Random();
int currentTop = 0;
while (!Console.KeyAvailable) { // Repeat until a key is hit.
                                // Create random dollars in top row
    for (int i = 0; i < Columns; i++) {
        buffer[currentTop][i] = random.NextDouble() < 0.1 ? '$' : ' ';
    }

    // Display buffer
    Console.Clear();
    for (int row = 0; row < Rows; row++) {
        int rowIndex = (row + currentTop) % Rows;
        Console.CursorTop = row;
        Console.CursorLeft = 0;
        Console.Write(buffer[rowIndex]);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(100); // Display buffer during 0.1 seconds

    // Move currentTop upwards. This gives the illusion of falling dollars.
    currentTop = (currentTop - 1 + Rows) % Rows;
}
```

Note that it uses a circular buffer. I.e., we assume that the end of the buffer (the last row) is connected with the first row.

We achieve this by taking the row index modulo the number of rows. `%` is the modulo or [Remainder operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) in C#. This makes the indexes exceeding the maximum row index start over at 0.

I used [Jagged Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) to allow us writing a row with a single `Console.Write(buffer[rowIndex]);`